# How do you create Preference Activity and Preference Fragment on Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-xml, android-preferences

As I was following an old tutorial ([Créez des applications pour Android -> openclassroom](http://fr.openclassrooms.com/informatique/cours/creez-des-applications-pour-android)) I got stuck on this deprecated method `addPreferencesFromResource(int id)` from the PreferenceActivity class.

So my question is :

> What is the new way of creating Preferences in Android ?

Comment: It would be probably better to have this post in Q&A-style. This means put the question as the question, and put the answer to it as the answer instead of putting everything in the question. See also [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Well i would love to do so but i don't have the reputation for it ;( i'll do it whenever i can :)

Comment: This might be a helpful resource, but it is not a question that can be answered. You might want to take it down until you can self-answer. Once you can self-answer, you could put it back up.

Comment: OK but how do you get reputation then? Answering questions? Commenting? Sorry for all the questions but that's my first post as you may have noticed :)

Comment: @WannaGetHigh ask questions and give helpful answers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation. I think once you have a reputation of 15 points, you can self-answer.

Comment: @Ugo thanks for the answer ill do this then !

Comment: Dude, it would be way cooler if you made a real question, followed by an answer. This current "question" doesn't say much, and won't be very good for googling. Pls try make it look more like other questions on this site.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I found this post ([What to use instead of “addPreferencesFromResource” in a PreferenceActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822319/what-to-use-instead-of-addpreferencesfromresource-in-a-preferenceactivity)) that help me understand that you have to go through a `PreferenceFragment` in order to do it.

In the following explanation I use `your.package.` just to show that you have to put the package name. Everybody has its own package so please replace it with your package.

lets begin :

---

### 1. Preference Fragment

- Create your PreferenceFragment class

  > *MyPreferenceFragment*

  ```
  public class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
  {
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.fragment_preference);
      }
  }
  ```

- Then the associated xml resource

  > *fragment_preference.xml* (in the folder res/xml of your project)

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <PreferenceScreen
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <PreferenceCategory 
          android:title="FOO">

          <CheckBoxPreference
              android:key="checkBoxPref"
              android:title="check it out"
              android:summary="click this little box"/>

      </PreferenceCategory>

  </PreferenceScreen>
  ```

  That's all for the `Fragment` part.

---

### 2. Preference Activity

- Create the PreferenceActivity class

  > *MyPreferenceActivity*

  ```
  public class MyPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity
  {
      @Override
      public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target)
      {
          loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.headers_preference, target);
      }

      @Override
      protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName)
      {
          return MyPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
      }
  }
  ```

  **Do not forget** to override `isValidFragment(String fragmentName)` method as you will get punched in the face by your application ! ;) More seriously I have no idea why you need to do this but it is needed. If someone has an explanation about this I'd gladly read it :)

  ### EDIT :

  ---

  Thanks to kirtan403 I now know why it is needed : it has to be set because of an ([android framework fragment injection](https://securityintelligence.com/new-vulnerability-android-framework-fragment-injection/)).

  ---

  As you can see in the `onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target)` we load another xml file that contain the *headers* of the preference. In short, headers are the left part of the preference and the fragment are the right part (for tablet). For a phone you will first have the headers and when you click on an item the corresponding fragment will be put on top of the headers list.

  Read this article ([Multi-pane development in Android with Fragments - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#fragments_overview)) the images explain themselves.

- Then the associated xml resource

  > *headers_preference.xml* (in the folder res/xml of your project)

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <preference-headers
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <header 
          android:fragment="your.package.MyPreferenceFragment"
          android:title="Goto: Preference fragment"
          android:summary="An example of some preferences." />

  </preference-headers>
  ```

  As you may have noticed in the *header* section you have :

  `android:fragment="your.package.MyPreferenceFragment"`

  This will act as a Link to the fragment you want to show. On Tablet it will load on the right part and on the phone it will load on top of the current view.

---

### 3. Android Manifest

Now what you should do is to add your Activity to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Inside the `application` section add these lines :

```
<activity
    android:name="your.package.MyPreferenceActivity"
    android:label="Preferences">
</activity>
```

You will probably tell me :

> "Oh darling you forgot to put *android:launchMode="singleTask"* in your actvity"

But **DO NOT PUT THIS** as you will never load your fragment on phone. This error was solved by a great man ! This is the link to his blog ([Android header preferences on small screen/phone](http://zornsoftware.codenature.info/blog/android-header-preferences-on-small-screen-phone.html)).

---

### 4. Start the Preferences from Menu

Finally you need to add the ability to show this Preference !! To do so you will need 3 things :

- The Menu

  > *menu.xml* (in the folder res/menu of your project)

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <menu 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <item 
          android:id="@+id/preferences"
          android:title="Preferences" />

  </menu>
  ```

- Loading this Menu in your Main activity (not the PreferenceActivity) under the method `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
  {
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
      return true;
  }
  ```

- Starting the `MyPreferenceActivity` Activity when you click on that button.

  For that you will need to override the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method in your Main activity.

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
  {
      switch(item.getItemId())
      {
          case R.id.preferences:
          {
              Intent intent = new Intent();
              intent.setClassName(this, "your.package.MyPreferenceActivity");
              startActivity(intent);
              return true;
          }
      }

      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
  ```

---

Et voila les amis !

I haven't tested this code. I took it and modified it from my own code so I may have not well copy pasted things. If you encounter errors tell me, I'll try to figure out the problem and fix this.

I hope this post will help some people out there :D

Cheers !

Comment: fwiw I have added your links in (pls include a link name, in case the link goes dead in future it makes it possible to google for the page) & added some formatting to make it easier to read. Also made some minor changes based on best practices on this site. Feel free to change any of my edits - it is YOUR question after all. Oh, and you may as well go ahead and delete your above comments, cos they are now out of date. G'luck

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Thanks a lot for your help ! It is indeed easier to read it and also thank you for the advices I'll remember it for my next answers/questions on this site ! Keep riding your wave :)

Comment: @WannaGetHigh You mentioned about the isValidFragment() usage, why it is used. you can read more about it [here](https://securityintelligence.com/new-vulnerability-android-framework-fragment-injection/) . Because of the Vulnerability, this method was introduced in Android 4.4 Kitkat.

Comment: @kirtan403 Thanks a lot for the link now I understand why they did this :)

Comment: Hi, this was immensely helpful! any chance for a quick tip on how to display just the fragment, without any of the additional screen in the middle?

Comment: You need to override isValidFragment to prevent the Fragment Injection Vulnerability.
https://securityintelligence.com/new-vulnerability-android-framework-fragment-injection/

Comment: @Prashan ty for the link i already saw the exploit in kirtan403 comment :)

Answer (score 19):

I liked the solution from this post: http://alvinalexander.com/android/android-tutorial-preferencescreen-preferenceactivity-preferencefragment

.. because it seems the most compact for someone that just needs something very basic up and running quickly.  It has only one .java file and two small xml files.

> **Activity Config REMINDERS**
>
> After adding the 3 files to your project, Don't forget to
>
> A) Add the Prefs Activity to Manifest file
>    B) Add some way to launch the Prefs Activity .. e.g., a Button or Menu item

Add the following files to your project. Use the order they are listed in to avoid compile errors.

1. Add /res/values/array.xml

   ```
   <resources>
       <string-array name="listArray">
           <item>Ace</item>
           <item>Club</item>
       </string-array>

       <string-array name="listValues">
           <item>Ace</item>
           <item>Club</item>
       </string-array>
   </resources>
   ```
2. Add /res/xml/preferences.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <EditTextPreference android:title="Your Name"
                           android:key="username"
                           android:summary="Please provide your username"></EditTextPreference>
       <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Application Updates"
                           android:defaultValue="false"
                           android:summary="This option if selected will allow the application to check for latest versions."
                           android:key="applicationUpdates" />
       <ListPreference     android:title="Download Details"
                           android:summary="Select the kind of data that you would like to download"
                           android:key="downloadType"
                           android:defaultValue="Ace"
                           android:entries="@array/listArray"
                           android:entryValues="@array/listValues" />
   </PreferenceScreen>
   ```
3. Add the Activity code

   ```
   public class AppPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity
   {
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();

           checkValues();
       }

       public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
       {
           @Override
           public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
           {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
           }
       }

       private void checkValues()
       {
           SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
           String strUserName = sharedPrefs.getString("username", "NA");
           boolean bAppUpdates = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("applicationUpdates",false);
           String downloadType = sharedPrefs.getString("downloadType","1");

           String msg = "Cur Values: ";
           msg += "\n userName = " + strUserName;
           msg += "\n bAppUpdates = " + bAppUpdates;
           msg += "\n downloadType = " + downloadType;

           Toaster.shortDebug(msg);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I want to show a settings Screen as a fragment (not as an activity)... is it possible to do so in a fragment.