# How to create my own Settings Activity and save it's values?

Tags: android, android-activity, settings

So this is the situation. I have created a simple google map in android. I have created another Activity (Settings.class) for Map settings. It has toggle buttons for customization of the app (notification "on/off", vibrate "on/off", sounds "on/off"). I want to use the values of these buttons to customize the map and the whole app, but every time I close/call another activity, the values were not retained. Can you help me what approach should I use?

Comment: Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html. Here is a good tutorial about this http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-preferences-activity-example/

Comment: Yeah shared preference

Answer (score 0):

> Those values are getting lost

That's because the activity has been destroyed when you close it. Either you could save it in a file/SharePreferences/sqlite storage and restore them when your activity is shown again.

Please read [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwjTgfLi0K_IAhWDjo4KHScHCEw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fguide%2Ftopics%2Fdata%2Fdata-storage.html&usg=AFQjCNGp43XUcnNOhRE7DytXA07IG44RHw&sig2=2Y-ujV1S-v_m6I7wUJGCTw&bvm=bv.104615367,d.c2E) about all these methods to store the values.

> A Small Suggestion

You can also use a Preference Activity , for it will help you get the state changes in your toggle buttons. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523806/how-do-you-create-preference-activity-and-preference-fragment-on-android).