# Error when calling the second activity using a button

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

[image]I have a problem calling a second activity using a password recovery button. I get the app stopped.

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }

    fun goToRecover(view: View) {
        val intent = Intent(this,RecoverPasswordActivity::class.java)
        this.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you declared RecoverPasswordActivity correctly in the AndroidManifest.xml? Please take a look at similar stackoverflow posts: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908534/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-unable-to-find-explicit-activity-clas 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293314/unable-to-find-explicit-activity-class-have-you-declared-this-activity-in-your

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the onClick in the XML-layout like this?

```
android:onClick="/*your method name*/"
```

If so, make sure that there are no typos. In your case it would probably be:

```
android:onClick="addOne"
```

OR

You can also listen for the click events programmatically. like below:

set the **Button** in **OnCreate** method:

```
var goToRecoverBtn = findViewById(R.id./*id name here*/)
```

after that add the ClickListener to the **goToRecoverBtn**:

```
goToRecoverBtn.setOnClickListener{
         // do anything whatever you want
}
```

OR

MainActivity code looks like below

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var goToRecoverBtn = findViewById(R.id./*id name here*/)

        goToRecoverBtn.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, RecoverPasswordActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }


    }
}
```

BTW could you please show us your .xml file?

Comment: yes, add the onClick to the XML layout, how can I put the xml code? won't let me put more code

Comment: @JavierMedina You can do it by clicking on the edit button (2nd button from the left hand sideor below your tags)

Comment: If I try that, but I got a message indicating that my question has more code and that I must enter more text; I managed to put as you recommend but still do not get me up, maybe the dependencies?

Comment: @JavierMedina try to post screenshot link

Comment: @JavierMedina did you try to call onClick programmatically

Comment: add screenshot of the proy, thansk